# Automating reorder of pages in PDF documents

Tags: javascript, .net, pdf, automation

I receive PDF documents regularly for review which are scanned over. Most of the times the sender does not scan the pages in order of the page numbers. I am trying to build a script to be able to detect the page numbers in the scanned document and re-arrange the pages in the document by number. (Something like automating Adobe Reader's in-built functionality of reordering pages)

Eg: PDF scanned over to me has 9 pages. They have been scanned over in this order: 2,5,1,3,4,9,7,8,6 and I am looking to order it as 1,2,3...9

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I guess you can use a library that extracts the pdf text, then you can look with a regular experssion the number page, for instance 1/10 (or something ilke that). With that you can save the pages with the numbe rof the page and reorder.

Comment: Thanks for that! Will try it out and see if it works. :)